# Error in mscorlib.dll when trying to connect my program with Google Sheets Api

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to connect my program to the google drive, to read a spreadsheet. I did the tutorial provided by google developers, https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet , but I'm getting some dll errors.

The erros that I get is

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll"

I get this error in this part of the code:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

How to troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: The `AggregateException` should have a nested exception which is very likely to give you much more information - please look at that, and then put it in your post.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your Visual Studio, mine is VS2015. Select Debug / Options, then go to "Debugging / General" and unselect the "Enable Just My Code" option.

Please try this:

```
try 
{
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,                                  
                                        DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                                "user",
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    WriteLine(ex.Message + " Error Details: " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

Here you have the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) for AggregateException Class and a post about this [topic](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/).

Comment: I did your proposal, and get this error details: 80004005):Access is denied at : System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes(), System.Net.HttpListener.Start() ... errors like that. What do you think about it?

Comment: My intention with Try/Catch block was to give a diagnostic of the situation you've got in hads. Is your application a C# console app or you're developing a web app? If It's a console app, try running as Administrator this app (open your Visual Studio as Admin).

On the other hand If It's not a web app, let me do some research.